# How does c# KeyedCollection initialize?

Tags: c#

I'm reading some c# source codes.And something confuses me.In the following code,OptionSet is inherited from class KeyedCollection,and when OptionSet initialize like the following,it will at first call OptionSet() to get a new but empty OptionSet,then call Add() twice to insert { "h|?|help", v => Syntax() } and { "analyzer=", v => analyzer = v }.

I want to know why it initializes like this,why use Add()?

```
var p = new OptionSet()
    {
        { "h|?|help", v => Syntax() },
        { "analyzer=", v => analyzer = v },
    }

public class OptionSet : KeyedCollection<string, Option>{
    public OptionSet ()
        {
        }
    public OptionSet Add (string prototype, Action<string> action){...}
    ...
    }
```

Comment: This looks like `nDesk.Options` to me. Have you [read the manual](http://www.ndesk.org/Options)? It seems like you're asking for the rationale behind its design. I'm not sure SO is the best place for such a discussion.

Comment: ...or perhaps this is a very poorly asked "How do collection initializers work" question? In which case, it's very likely to be a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry,I've searched MSDN but find nothing helpful for my question,so I came here to ask.Actually what I really want to ask is "How do collection initializers work,why they use Add",and the answer I expected is some official documentation about the whole initializer's working mechanism.And I'm reading an open-source project Peach's source code,I haven't read the manual you mentioned.And thanks : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var p = new AnyCollection()
{
    ...
}
```

you are using [Collection initializers](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/collection-initializers/).

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_2):

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements
>   IEnumerable or a class with an Add extension method. The element
>   initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an object
>   initializer. By using a collection initializer **you do not have to**
>   **specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source**
>   **code; the compiler adds the calls.**

Comment: Thanks,that's what I want.

Comment: And... why the downvote? Please comment so one can improve

Comment: I can't vote now(< 15 reputation),so I also don't know why : (